# Finding power series representation at a=1

Tags: calculus

$$f(x) = \frac {2}{x+2}; a=1$$

Find the power series representation at $a = 1$ for $f(x)$ and determine its radius and interval of convergence.

Whenever I try to simply $f(x)$ i get some weird answer, any tips?

Comment: If you rearrange $f$, you might recognize the sum of a geometric series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t=x-1\iff x=t+1$ then
$$f(x)=\frac2{t+3}=\frac23\frac1{1+\frac t3}=\frac23\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nt^n}{3^n}=\frac23\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(x-1)^n}{3^n}$$

Comment: How would i go about finding the radius\interval of cvg?

Comment: Use the ratio test for the radius and you find $R=3$ and the interval of cv is $(-2,4)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $2/(x+2) = 2/((x-1) + 3) = (2/3)(2/((x-1)/3 + 1))$